# How can I create such a form and write text inside it?

Tags: tcolorbox, mdframed, box

[image]

How can I create such a form and write text inside it?

Comment: check the tcolorbox package.

Comment: I do not know how to do this

Comment: please show us a sample of document where you like to have such boxes. knowing it the adding of rounded boxes will be easy.

Comment: Note that every package comes with a manual.  They are usually installed with the package.   In my case `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\latex\tcolorbox\tcolorbox.pdf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can see the version of my MWE with the use of [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package. The text is automatically justified and for further clarification you can also leave me a message or a comment. The color of the border you want is set by the variation of this amount `!70` and you can increase the arc with the value `arc=5mm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtcolorbox{rounded}{
  breakable,
  colback=white,
  colframe=darkgray!70,
  arc=5mm
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{rounded}
\textbf{Résumé}\\
\lipsum[5]
\end{rounded}
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM:** I adding another MWE with indent: `\tcbset{before upper={\parindent1.5em}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbset{before upper={\parindent1.5em}}

\newtcolorbox{rounded}{
  breakable,
  colback=white,
  colframe=darkgray!70,
  arc=5mm
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{rounded}
\textbf{Résumé}\\

\lipsum[6]
\end{rounded}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`mdframed`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed?lang=en) package (with the `TikZ` option for the rounded edges). You first define your style and then apply it where you need it.

Here is an example that would give you the boxes you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\mdfdefinestyle{rounded}{
linecolor=gray,
linewidth=2pt,
roundcorner=20pt,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
innerbottommargin=\topskip
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=rounded]
\textbf{Résumé}\par
\lipsum[1-2]\par
\textbf{Mots clés:} Your keywords
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[style=rounded]
\textbf{Summary}\par
\lipsum[3-3]\par
\textbf{Keywords:} Your keywords
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

(The `lipsum` package and the `\lipsum` commands are added just to generate some filler text, you don't need them)

It will look like this:

[image]